# Crashed while printing (adhesion issue? Level issue?)

Tags: pla, creality-ender-6

Printing with "Amolen bronze PLA", success with smaller prints.

Decided to print the "Fillenium M", but it crashed at 50 % during the print.

I assume the print fell down (due to raft failure).
Or, it might be some other issues (no idea?).

Temperatures are:

- Extruder 190 °C
- Bed 50 °C

In your experience, what would be most likely culprit?
Picture attached below (see the notch where the nozzle crashed into print)

- Amolen Bronze PLA
- Creality CR-6 SE 1.0.2
- Creality Slicer 4.2.1

[image]

Comment: It is very hard for us to answer this question, there are too many unknowns. Generally, the use of a raft is not necessary and from the image cannot be concluded that the raft is the issue. Bed temperature for PLA can be seen as too low, but that depends on the used filament.

Comment: Thanks. I should finish my octoprint box. That'd be handy for fails like this one.